# Are all protein composed of all the amino acid (in animal) or are there less diverse protein?

Tags: proteins

I have a question about amino acid composition of proteins: Are there proteins in animals that are made up only from a small subset of amino acids? So instead of all 20 amino acids let's say only 6-14 ( or any arbitrarily small subset) amino acids are used in a particular protein. Could you give me an example (or maybe a few examples) of such protein(s).

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! I took the liberty to reformulate the body of your question. You can revert to your original version at any time if you wish.

Comment: This may interest you: http://www.nature.com/srep/2013/131010/srep02919/full/srep02919.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trp-Cage](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1L2Y) is a protein found in Gila monsters, and it is only 20 amino acids long and there are plenty of repeated amino acids so this does not use all 20. But there must be plenty of other examples, there is no reason why physically a protein must use all available amino acids.